# UNIQUE function with IF-Condition containing multiple AND-Conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
  |    A   |    B   |    C   |    D   |    E   |    F    |     
--|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|---------|-------
1 |    1   |        |  2021  |  2022  |  2021  |   2022  |
2 |    1   |        |  test  |    1   |  test  |         |
3 |    1   |        |    2   |    2   |    2   |         |
4 |    2   |        |    3   |    3   |    3   |         |
5 |    3   |        |        |        |        |         |
6 |    3   |        |        |        |        |         |
7 |    1   |        |        |        |        |         |
```

---

In `Columns C:E` I want to insert a unique list of the values in `Column A`.

Additionally, **if**

1. the value in `Row 1` is smaller than the value in `Cell $F$1` **AND**
2. one of the `UNIQUE` values equals the number `1`

**then** the word `"test"` should be displayed instead of the number 1.

---

I tried to go with this formula:

```
C2:E2 = =IF(AND(C$1<$F$1,UNIQUE($A$1:$A$7)=1),"test",UNIQUE($A$1:$A$7))
```

However, somehow this formula ignores the conditions and keeps displaying a `1` instead of the word `test`.

What do I need to change to make it work?

Comment: Something like `=LET(x,UNIQUE($A1:$A7),IF(AND(C1<$F1,COUNTIF($A1:$A7,1)),IF(x=1,"test",x),x))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the multiplication sign (*) instead of AND in array formulas:

```
=IF((C$1<$F$1)*(UNIQUE($A$1:$A$7)=1),"test",UNIQUE($A$1:$A$7))
```

[image]